# Abandoned village to Village

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Minecraft has generated an abandoned village in my world. Is there any way to turn the zombie village that has never been a village into a village?

**EDIT:** I have one golden apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A village is formed when a villager associates with beds, there is no need for there to be any particular pre-generated structure. So if you cure a zombie villager then you will technically have a village but you probablly want at least two so you can breed more villagers.

To cure each zombie villager requires applying the weakness status effect (usually using a splash potion of weakness), then giving them a golden apple. Once you have two villagers you can breed them to get more. I would recommend doing this undercover so the zombie doesn't get itself killed in the sunlight.

If all the zombie villagers are already dead or you don't want to be bothered curing them you could also transport in villagers from another village using boats or mine carts.